# Sort tab delimited text fields involving spaces

Tags: unix, sorting

I am having difficulty with the Unix `sort` command when tab delimited fields are introduced.

If a file `test.txt` contains:

```
Hello (2)
Hello (1)
Hello
```

applying a sort:

```
sort test.txt
```

produces the output:

```
Hello
Hello (1)
Hello (2)
```

However, if a file `test2.txt` contains tab separated fields:

```
Hello (2)\tFred
Hello (1)\tFred
Hello\tFred
```

where `\t` is a tab character, applying a sort:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 1,2 test2.txt
```

results in a different sort order.

```
Hello (1)   Fred
Hello (2)   Fred
Hello   Fred
```

Is there a way to use the `sort` command so that the tab delimited fields will be sorted like this:

```
Hello   Fred
Hello (1)   Fred
Hello (2)   Fred
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort` uses your current locale for sorting. I am using `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` myself and I get your "undesired" result. Using the `C` locale, I get your desired result:

```
$ LANG=C sort -t $'\t' -k 1,2 test2.txt
Hello   Fred
Hello (1)       Fred
Hello (2)       Fred
```